# How to create a series of fractions, such that each subsequence slice is smaller than the previous?

Tags: fractions

I need to develop a grading system for a course. The first assignment is evaluated based on only one criteria, *a*. The second assignment based on the first criteria, *a*, plus one new criteria, *b*, the third assignment based on three criteria, *a*, *b*, and *c*, etc. The 16th assignment is graded based on 16th criteria, *a* through *p*.

```
Assignment 1: a
Assignment 2: a+b
Assignment 3: a+b+c
…
```

I initially devised this distribution:

```
Assignment 1: 1
Assignment 2: 1/2+1/2
Assignment 3: 1/3+1/3+1/3
…
Assignment 16: 1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16+1/16, 1/16+1/16+1/16
```

This does not suit the problem well though, because the first criteria introduced are the most important, so the earlier criteria should always take more weight than later criteria. I need a system where *a* is always greater than *b* and *b* is always greater than *c*, meanwhile, making sure that *p* never gets to be too much smaller than ~1/50 or so.

```
 Assignment 16: a > b > c > d > e > f > g > h > i > j > k > l > m > n > o > p
```

How can I distribute the value of each criteria for the assignments?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're looking for.  The first display says that assignment 1 has distribution $a$, and assignment 2 has distribution $a+b$.  But then when I match this up with the second display, it seems to  say that for assignment 1, $a=1$ and for assignment 2, $a=\frac12$.  I don't understand what $a, b, c\ldots$ are supposed to represent here.  Could you please edit your question to clarify this?

Comment: As an example, for assignment 1, "Correct spelling", *a*, is worth 1/1, or 100%. For assignment 2, "Correct spelling" is worth 1/2 or 50% and the new criteria, "Correct punctuation", *b*, is worth 1/2, or 50%. *a* is how important the first criteria is to the grade, but this value gets smaller in later assignments, but should always be larger than *b*.

Comment: There are obvious many choices of assignment. I think a decision you need to make is how much weight you want to assign to $a$ in $n^{th}$ assignment as $n$ changes. Do you want it goes like $\frac{1}{n}$ i.e. every choices roughly equal at the end or the weight of $a$ remains finite as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need fractions?  You can make them an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).  For assignment $k$, the average weight is $\frac 1k$.  Let the difference between terms be $d$.  The weights range from $\frac 1k+\frac{(k-1)d}2$ to $\frac 1k-\frac {(k-1)d}2$.  So if $k=15, d=0.005, \frac 1k \approx 0.066667$ and the weights range from $0.1016667$ down to $0.0316667$.  Now you just have to pick a $d$ for each $k$ that makes you happy.  Then you can convert these back to fractions if you want.